# Given a sequences of eigenvalues could we find a corresponding operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$ for n=1,2,... Could one expect to find a a self-adjoint operator $A$ on a Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$, such that $\lambda_n(A)=a_n$ for all n=1,2,... Just this characterize the spectrum of such an operator that would have a cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$.

What kind of assumptions on the coefficients $a_n$ one needs in order to have such an existence? Is there something on the literature about this problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^2<\infty$ is the necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: First of all, the eigenvalues need to be real-valued if A should be self-adjoint. If you allow unbounded operators $A$, then any real-valued sequence can be the spectrum. Such a construction can be made for any separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$. Let $e_n$ be an ONB for $H$. Then we define $A = \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} \lambda_n(A) P_{e_n}$, where $P_n$ is the projection onto the span of $e_n$. Unfortunately, I don't directly see if one can choose the domain of A such that it is densely defined and self-adjoint. This construction only yields a symmetric densely defined operator...

Comment: Ok, dom$(A) := \{x\in H: \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} \lambda_n(A)^2 |\langle x, e_n\rangle |^2<\infty\}$. Will do the job. It is dense and $A$, dom$(A)$ is selfadjoint, since its spectrum is real and A is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, we need $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ if you want something self-adjoint. If you just want normal operators this condition is not necessary anymore.

Think about a matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1&0&0&\cdots\\
0&a_2&0&\cdots\\
0&0&a_3&\cdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{bmatrix}$$

If we were in finite dimension $k$, and there were only values $a_1,\ldots,a_k$, this would work. What is the associated operator in this case? You can then figure out what the infinite-dimensional analogue is.

In the infinite-dimensional case,

- The operator associated to $A$ is continuous if $\sup_i|a_i|<\infty$, but in this case you may have extra eigenvalues (e.g. if $a_i=\sqrt{2}^{-i}$ then $0$ is also an eigenvalue)
- The operator associated to $A$ is only densely defined otherwise.